# swift: send value back to UITableViewController from dynamic cell with UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, datepicker, tableview, uitableview

I've got a dynamic table with a cell for a UIDatePicker.  There's a function in the UITableViewCell class that updates a variable when the picker changes.  I'm just having trouble getting that value back to the UITableViewController class.  I can print the correct variable while spinning the picker, but when I go to reloadRowsAtIndexPaths for the tableView I need the value available.

Since there's no segue, I can't get a protocol/delegate to work.  I imagine a global variable might also work, but that's cheating.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` for storing values globally which can access anywhere into your project. you can set values this way for your picker.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("YouValueForm", forKey: "YourKey")
```

After that you can access this value anywhere in your project this way:

```
let yourVar = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("YourKey") as! String
```

You can modify this as per your need. and once you got your values you can do `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Hope this will help.